# Flask testing create_app is not returning the application?

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-testing

I am working on setting up unit tests in my flask project right now. My test file is below:

```
import flask_testing
import unittest
from flask import Flask
from flask_testing import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass # Executed before each test

    def tearDown(self):
        pass # Executed after each test

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        # app.config['TESTING'] = True
        return app

    def test_greeting(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        print("should return 404 on landing page")
        self.assertTemplateUsed('index.html')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run these tests the `assertTemplateUsed` does not return a template and the `response.status_code` is 404. I imagine this is because self is not actually my application for some reason? When I run the app the root address definitely returns index.html.

Am I setting up `create_app` wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your Flask app instance in the `setUp()` function. At the moment the `create_app()` function doesn't get called at all.

Change your code like this:

```
import flask_testing
import unittest
from flask import Flask
from flask_testing import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookie=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_greeting(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        print("should return 404 on landing page")
        self.assertTemplateUsed('index.html')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The `setUp()` function gets called prior to each test function. At first you will create a new instance of your Flask app. If you want to access items in your application context it is good practice to push it in your `setUp()` function and pop it in your `tearDown()` function. You can leave this out if you don' t access app_context items (like Database session objects) from your test function. At last you need to creat the test client in your `setUp()` function. You missed that part in your post but I guess you did it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: create_app() is definitely being called. It's required in Flask-Testing applications: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/ Edit: I could however just try and drop flask-testing and just use unittest

Answer (score 1):

In your setUp function, you need to provide a test client to make the requests. Try something like this.

```
def setUp(self):
    # this test client is what flask-testing will use to make your requests
    self.app = app.test_client()
```

Check this out for more information [How to Test a Flask Application](https://damyanon.net/post/flask-series-testing/).